# How to auto-complete/auto-close brackets on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, autocorrect

Some text editors for programming support auto-closing brackets. For example, on Jupyter Notebook or Jupyterlab for Python, given a line, say

> asdf wert xcvb

If I double-click to highlight *wert*, and I type *(*, it will give me

> asdf (wert) xcvb

Similarly, if I highlight *asdf*, and type *'*, it will give me

> 'asdf' wert scvb

Is there a way to do so in the entire Mac OS?

Comment: I think that what you are asking for would lead to unforeseen consequences. I believe the answer is `No`. Try asking here instead: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any such global behavior, as what you describe is the
special behavior of this one specific app.

To recreate this for the entire operating system, you will need a
system macro, activated by some chosen keyboard key,
that will translate it to a series of keys to achieve the desired effect.

For example (taken from Windows and needs to be translated to the Mac),
the keyboard combination of
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> could be translated to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,
<kbd>(</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,
<kbd>)</kbd>.
For the Mac, substitute <kbd>Win</kbd> by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

This will cut the selection to the clipboard, enter `(`,
paste the selection, finally enter `)`.
This combination should work for most applications.

You may do the same with characters other than parenthesis, such as quotes.

For a discussion of macro programs on the Mac, see the post
[AutoHotkey Equivalent for OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is through **System preferences.**

- Go to **System Preferences  > Keyboard > Text**
- Click the '**+**' button in the bottom left.
- Enter the shortcut text you want in the **Replace** column(In our case it will be *'('* ).
- Enter the target phrase that you want to expand to in the **With** column (In this case, "()").
- Repeat the above steps for all the different types of brackets(if required)
- Each time you type an opening bracket, the system will show the expansion below the text, and will automatically replace it with the desired result when you press "Space" or "Enter".

Enveloping highlighted text in brackets or quotes doesn't seem possible with this, though.

**Source:**
https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/autocomplete-with-text-shortcuts-os-x

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a text editor with this functionality then I'd suggest [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/).

I'm sure there are others, this just happens to be the one I use and it behaves exactly as you describe.